# Selecting all columns and adding extra column using foreign key ID

Tags: database, postgresql

I've got a table (table one) with a foreign key ID that points to another table (table two). I'm trying to select all the columns in table one, but also additionally add a specific column from table two based off a specific WHERE condition. Just wondering how to accomplish this in Postgres? For example, something like this is what I'm going for, however I'm not sure of the appropriate syntax I should be using:

```
select *, (second_table.name AS `name` FROM second_table WHERE first_table.id=second_table.id) FROM first_table
```

A basic example of the structure:

**Table one:** id, something1, something2

**Table two:** id, name

**The output I'm looking for:** id=x, name=x, something1=x, something2=x

The reason I need the column to be named 'name' is so that I can deserialize it directly into a Golang struct (which is expecting the column to be named 'name'). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `JOIN` SQL instruction. A quick example to get you going:

```
SELECT 
    one.id AS id,
    one.something1 AS something1,
    one.something2 AS something2,
    two.name AS name
FROM one
JOIN two ON one.id = two.id
```

The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) about jointures is a good starting point to get more informations.